# Why can't I implement Google places API?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am trying to implement the `Place Picker` API by Google. But every time I start the activity, it just closes instantly.

*Code for implementing Place Picker:*

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_2);

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            try {
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

*The API key has been declared in my manifest file:*

```
<manifest>

<application

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_place_api" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

*Logcat error:*

```
    BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/search?key=AIzaSyCHWpRWCGo_YUKwzHn4Qv6yP5q9E5TNRJA
2019-04-28 07:49:21.729 2875-5225/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
```

Why does this error occur even though Google places is enabled on my account?

**Note:** I have also set up my billing account.

Comment: PlacePicker has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app: double check it

```
    private void openAutocompleteActivity(int req) {
    try {

        PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
        //   .build(this);
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), req);

        // PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder1= new PlacePicker().IntentBuilder();
        // startActivity(builder1.build(this), 112);
        //  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this,  
        e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                0 /* requestCode */).show();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);


    //    Log.e(TAG, message);
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

/**
 * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
 */

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.



        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

            LatLng xyzlatlng= place.getLatLng();
            double lat=xyzlatlng.latitude;
            double lon=xyzlatlng.longitude;
        }
      }
```